Какую библиотеку использовать вместо sticky.js для липкого элемента?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, библиотеку на замену sticky.js, т.к необходимо сделать липкий элемент, а метод destroy в sticky.js не работает

Что насчет position: sticky?

@OliverPatterson, спасибо, использовал ваш совет. Проблема заключалась в том, что я пробовал использовать sticky, но он не срабатывал. А сейчас прочитал, что он не срабатывает, если нужный элемент занимает всю высоту родительского блока. А у меня как раз заголовок из-за flex занимал всю высоту родительского блока


...на замену sticky.js

cleanup() вместо destroy() в библиотеке Stickybits


var stickyInstance = stickybits('#stickyElement', {
  useStickyClasses: true
});

console.log('Stickybits initialized:', stickyInstance);

setTimeout(function() {
  stickyInstance.cleanup();
  console.log('Stickybits destroyed');

  var element = document.getElementById('stickyElement');
  element.classList.add('destroyed');

  element.textContent = "Sticky effect has been destroyed!";
}, 5000);
.container {
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.your-sticky-element {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.destroyed {
  background-color: lightcoral !important;
  color: white;
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/stickybits@3.7.8/dist/stickybits.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="your-sticky-element" id="stickyElement">I'm sticky!</div>
</div>



